# Are employer contributions to RRSP part of one's own contributions in tax forms?

Tags: taxes, canada, rrsp, quebec

*Context: working for a company in Quebec (Canada) that matches RRSP contributions.*

When contributing to one's RRSP, the company contributes an additional amount on top (a percentage of the employee contribution up to a fixed amount).

In tax declarations to the CRA and Revenu Québec, what should one report as RRSP contributions?

1. the total amount? (employee part + company part)
2. or only the employee part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Summary

The company contribution is declared as part of the employee's income, and as such it is included in the T4 slip as employment income (part of box 14).

The employee should declare the total RRSP contribution (employee + company), as seen on bank receipts.

The contribution limit given on the Notification of Assessment is also for the total contribution (employee + company).

## Official CRA answer

> [The company's] RRSP contribution is a taxable benefit to the employee. Enter code 40 in the “Other information” area and the corresponding amount in the box. Also include this amount in box 14.

From the CRA's [Employers' Guide – Filing the T4 Slip and Summary](https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/forms-publications/publications/rc4120/employers-guide-filing-t4-slip-summary.html#Step6arrspcontribution).

## Related questions

- [Do employer RRSP contributions show up as income on my T4?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/24313/do-employer-rrsp-contributions-show-up-as-income-on-my-t4)
- [Do employer matching contributions in an RRSP count towards the contribution room?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/46326/do-employer-matching-contributions-in-an-rrsp-count-towards-the-contribution-roo)
- [Should I enter the total RRSP contributions from my pension plan? Or is this double counting deductions?](https://turbotax.community.intuit.ca/community/seniors-students/discussion/if-i-enter-line-20-from-my-t4-do-i-still-enter-the-total-rrsp-contributions-from-my-pension-plan/00/910841)